# Accessing subroute parameters from parent route. react-router

Tags: react-router-v4

Consider a drop-down menu that routes when changed.

Logically we have a layout as so:

```
<Things>
    {/* Dropdown menu that, when item is selected, 
        routes to appropriate Thing-specific path */}
    <ThingsDropdown />

    {/* Component that represents the currently selected thing. */}
    <Thing />
</Things>
```

The idea being that the top-level here is /things/, and choosing an item from the dropdown routes to /things/:thingId/.

When loading /things/:thingId/ directly, the value of the dropdown should default to :thingId. But the parent component (Things) does not have access to the Thing-specific parameter.

This is not a problem unique to React Router. Ember's routing system has the same limitation.

What is the recommended pattern for dealing with this use case? It seems wasteful to have to specify the current thingId twice (once as a parameter, and once in state so that it can be set correctly in the parent component).

Thanks.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I've determined the solution here is to use a Route that always renders, and to determine the selected thingId by looking at the match parameter (if set) passed to the component.